# php loop statement question

Tags: php, loops

I'm wondering if it is possible to loop a variable within a variable? Here is something I want to setup:

```
$var1 = Benjamin
$var2 = George
$var3 = Abraham
```

and probably echo out something like

```
<li>Benjamin</li>
<li>George</li>
<li>Abraham</li>
```

*but* I want to know, if I want to add `$var4 = ..., $var5 = ...`, is there a way I can do this all in a loop? I'm thinking having an `empty()` function that'll loop the variable names/numbers until reaches the first empty variable?

Comment: im confused, but i think the answer is an array()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP you can do this:

```
    $var1 = "foo";
    $var2 = "bar";

    $name = "var1";
    $i=1;
    while( !is_null( $$name ) ) {
            echo '<li>' . $$name . '</li>';
            $i++;
            $name = "var$i";
    }
```

but a better solution may be using an array and a foreach

Comment: Bonus for answering the question asked and caveating it.

Comment: wow as the others have said, thanks for creating this. It helps me learn more about how to use php!

Comment: +1 for variable variables. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @Zydeco: Variable variables are _not_ to be +1'd.

Comment: @Tomalak: If you feel that way, then don't, but be considerate of the fact that not everyone thinks like you do. Variable variables are extremely useful and not many people utilize them at all.

Comment: @Zydeco: Variable variables decrease legibility, proveability and maintainability. Especially when the only variable part of your variable name is an integer, arrays are _designed_ for the purpose and are far superior by almost any measure.

Answer (score 7):

You could store them in an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

```
$names = array('Mike', 'Jim', 'Tom', 'Stacy');

foreach($names as $name){
  echo $name;
}
```

As seen here: http://www.ideone.com/f7Ce7

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you want to use arrays and `foreach`. Am I missing something?

```
$presidents = array(
  'Benjamin', 'George', 'Abraham'
);

foreach($presidents as $pres) {
 echo "$pres\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$var=array('Benjamin', 'George', 'Abraham');

foreach ($var as $name){
echo $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be arrays.
define it as:
`$names = array(0=>"Benjamin",1=>"George",2=>"Abraham");`

Then loop through it with:

```
foreach ($names as $id=>$name)
{
    echo $name;
}
```

Then reference a name with `$names[0]`, if you want to add another use `$names[] = 'William';`
Look up more information at:http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't require the use of an array.

```
$var1 = 'Benjamin';
$var2 = 'George';
$var3 = 'Abraham';
//add as many variables as you want

$i = 0;
$currentVariable = 'var'.$i;
while (isset($$currentVariable)) {
    //process variable
    echo $$currentVariable;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't require an array, but an array is the best solution. This is what arrays were created for, back in 1940s. However, you do get credit for answering the literal question correctly. :)

Comment: Agreed, Tomalak.  An array is the best solution the majority of the time.  Variable variables are useful in a handful of cases though.